# Custom Callout on MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wish to show a completely custom callout view on top of the `MKAnnotationView` when tapped. I have stumbled through a few answers but none of them have worked and I have seen it in a few apps so I know it can be done. I would also like to show a few buttons on the callout and perform different actions upon tapping on them. I am working on Objective-C and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your custom code on **viewForAnnotation** method and update view as per your requirement:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[YOUR_CUSOM_ANNO_CLASS_NAME class]]) // use whatever annotation class you used when creating the annotation
    {
        static NSString * const identifier = @"customAnno";

        MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (annotationView)
        {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        else
        {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                          reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        }

        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES; 
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:];

        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

There is a wonderful [demo](https://github.com/sghiassy/Custom-MKAnnotationView) by sghiassy on github. It will help you more to understand Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 9 you can use the detailCalloutAccessoryView property on MKAnnotationView. You can set this to any view. You have a Ray Wenderlich tutorial for this on Chapter 14 of iOS 9 by Tutorials.